# Integers and booleans posted via $.ajax converted to strings by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, casting

I have some fairly standard jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myurl,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        id: 5,
        status: true
    }
});
```

When PHP receives that and automagically decodes the JSON data, integers and booleans are converted to strings. This is bad news because further down the line there are some functions that check for type equivalency.

Any ideas how I can get PHP to decode nicely?

Comment: The basic nature of an HTTP request is such that *all* parameters are strings. The "dataType" property to the ajax options says what you expect the *return* data to look like. Your input parameters will be sent as an ordinary query string in the POST body.

Comment: why don't you just cast the values to their respective types once you receive them from the form? this way, you will be forwarding the data with the right types. For example, in php: `$id = (int) $_POST['id'];`

Comment: @muhammad, I figured at the end of the day i could do that I just didn’t know if I was missing something. 

Comment: @BenjaminAllison Check answer below for another option, where types are kept.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: myurl,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    id: 5,
    status: true
  })
});
```

Then on PHP side:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$object = json_decode($input);
```

In this case, `$object->status` should be a boolean (and rest of data should keep their original type as well).

Not sure this is worth it though. You could simply check the types against what they should be, like other people mentioned. [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is a solid way to do this.